# ActiveMQ Artemis master can't detect slave

Tags: high-availability, activemq-artemis

I am new to ActiveMQ Artemis and trying to configure master-slave setup. In my scenario, I am using one master and one slave.

Master's `broker.xml` looks like:

```xml
<configuration xmlns="...">

   <core xmlns="...">

      <name>10.168.100.41</name>
      <persistence-enabled>true</persistence-enabled>

      <journal-type>ASYNCIO</journal-type>
      <paging-directory>data/paging</paging-directory>
      <bindings-directory>data/bindings</bindings-directory>
      <journal-directory>data/journal</journal-directory>
      <large-messages-directory>data/large-messages</large-messages-directory>
      <journal-datasync>true</journal-datasync>
      <journal-min-files>2</journal-min-files>
      <journal-pool-files>10</journal-pool-files>
      <journal-device-block-size>4096</journal-device-block-size>
      <journal-file-size>10M</journal-file-size>
      
      
      <journal-buffer-timeout>28000</journal-buffer-timeout>


      <!--
        When using ASYNCIO, this will determine the writing queue depth for libaio.
       -->
      <journal-max-io>4096</journal-max-io>
      <!--
        You can verify the network health of a particular NIC by specifying the <network-check-NIC> element.
         <network-check-NIC>theNicName</network-check-NIC>
        -->

          
    <connectors>
        <!-- Connector used to be announced through cluster connections and notifications -->
        <connector name="artemis">tcp://10.168.100.41:61616</connector>
    </connectors>



      <!-- how often we are looking for how many bytes are being used on the disk in ms -->
      <disk-scan-period>5000</disk-scan-period>

      <!-- once the disk hits this limit the system will block, or close the connection in certain protocols
           that won't support flow control. -->
      <max-disk-usage>90</max-disk-usage>

      <!-- should the broker detect dead locks and other issues -->
      <critical-analyzer>true</critical-analyzer>

      <critical-analyzer-timeout>120000</critical-analyzer-timeout>

      <critical-analyzer-check-period>60000</critical-analyzer-check-period>

      <critical-analyzer-policy>HALT</critical-analyzer-policy>

      
      <page-sync-timeout>356000</page-sync-timeout>


            <!-- the system will enter into page mode once you hit this limit.
           This is an estimate in bytes of how much the messages are using in memory

            The system will use half of the available memory (-Xmx) by default for the global-max-size.
            You may specify a different value here if you need to customize it to your needs.

            <global-max-size>100Mb</global-max-size>

      -->

      <acceptors>

         <!-- useEpoll means: it will use Netty epoll if you are on a system (Linux) that supports it -->
         <!-- amqpCredits: The number of credits sent to AMQP producers -->
         <!-- amqpLowCredits: The server will send the # credits specified at amqpCredits at this low mark -->
         <!-- amqpDuplicateDetection: If you are not using duplicate detection, set this to false
                                      as duplicate detection requires applicationProperties to be parsed on the server. -->
         <!-- amqpMinLargeMessageSize: Determines how many bytes are considered large, so we start using files to hold their data.
                                       default: 102400, -1 would mean to disable large mesasge control -->

         <!-- Note: If an acceptor needs to be compatible with HornetQ and/or Artemis 1.x clients add
                    "anycastPrefix=jms.queue.;multicastPrefix=jms.topic." to the acceptor url.
                    See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-1644 for more information. -->


         <!-- Acceptor for every supported protocol -->
         <acceptor name="artemis">tcp://10.168.100.41:61616?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;amqpMinLargeMessageSize=102400;protocols=CORE,AMQP,STOMP,HORNETQ,MQTT,OPENWIRE;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300;amqpDuplicateDetection=true</acceptor>

        
         <acceptor name="amqp">tcp://10.168.100.41:5672?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=AMQP;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300;amqpMinLargeMessageSize=102400;amqpDuplicateDetection=true</acceptor>

         <!-- STOMP Acceptor. -->
         <acceptor name="stomp">tcp://10.168.100.41:61613?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=STOMP;useEpoll=true</acceptor>

         <!-- HornetQ Compatibility Acceptor.  Enables HornetQ Core and STOMP for legacy HornetQ clients. -->
         <acceptor name="hornetq">tcp://10.168.100.41:5445?anycastPrefix=jms.queue.;multicastPrefix=jms.topic.;protocols=HORNETQ,STOMP;useEpoll=true</acceptor>

         <!-- MQTT Acceptor -->
         <acceptor name="mqtt">tcp://10.168.100.41:1883?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=MQTT;useEpoll=true</acceptor>

      </acceptors>


      <cluster-user>username</cluster-user>

      <cluster-password>password</cluster-password>

      <broadcast-groups>
         <broadcast-group name="bg-group1">
            <group-address>231.7.7.7</group-address>
            <group-port>9876</group-port>
            <broadcast-period>5000</broadcast-period>
            <connector-ref>artemis</connector-ref>
         </broadcast-group>
      </broadcast-groups>

      <discovery-groups>
         <discovery-group name="dg-group1">
            <group-address>231.7.7.7</group-address>
            <group-port>9876</group-port>
            <refresh-timeout>10000</refresh-timeout>
         </discovery-group>
      </discovery-groups>

      <cluster-connections>
         <cluster-connection name="my-cluster">
            <connector-ref>artemis</connector-ref>
            <message-load-balancing>ON_DEMAND</message-load-balancing>
            <max-hops>0</max-hops>
            <discovery-group-ref discovery-group-name="dg-group1"/>
         </cluster-connection>
      </cluster-connections>


      <ha-policy>
         <replication>
            <master>
               <vote-on-replication-failure>true</vote-on-replication-failure>
            </master>
         </replication>
      </ha-policy>

      <security-settings>
         <security-setting match="#">
            <permission type="createNonDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="deleteNonDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="createDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="deleteDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="createAddress" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="deleteAddress" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="consume" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="browse" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="send" roles="amq"/>
            <!-- we need this otherwise ./artemis data imp wouldn't work -->
            <permission type="manage" roles="amq"/>
         </security-setting>
      </security-settings>

      <address-settings>
         <!-- if you define auto-create on certain queues, management has to be auto-create -->
         <address-setting match="activemq.management#">
            <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
            <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
            <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
            <!-- with -1 only the global-max-size is in use for limiting -->
            <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
            <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
            <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
            <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
            <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
            <auto-create-jms-queues>true</auto-create-jms-queues>
            <auto-create-jms-topics>true</auto-create-jms-topics>
         </address-setting>
         <!--default for catch all-->
         <address-setting match="#">
            <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
            <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
            <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
            <!-- with -1 only the global-max-size is in use for limiting -->
            <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
            <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
            <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
            <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
            <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
            <auto-create-jms-queues>true</auto-create-jms-queues>
            <auto-create-jms-topics>true</auto-create-jms-topics>
         </address-setting>
      </address-settings>

      <addresses>
         <address name="DLQ">
            <anycast>
               <queue name="DLQ" />
            </anycast>
         </address>
         <address name="ExpiryQueue">
            <anycast>
               <queue name="ExpiryQueue" />
            </anycast>
         </address>

      </addresses>
   </core>
</configuration>
```

Slave's `broker.xml` looks like:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<configuration xmlns="...">
   <core xmlns="...">

      <name>10.168.100.41</name>


      <persistence-enabled>true</persistence-enabled>

      <journal-type>ASYNCIO</journal-type>

      <paging-directory>data/paging</paging-directory>

      <bindings-directory>data/bindings</bindings-directory>

      <journal-directory>data/journal</journal-directory>

      <large-messages-directory>data/large-messages</large-messages-directory>

      <journal-datasync>true</journal-datasync>

      <journal-min-files>2</journal-min-files>

      <journal-pool-files>10</journal-pool-files>

      <journal-device-block-size>4096</journal-device-block-size>

      <journal-file-size>10M</journal-file-size>
      
      <journal-buffer-timeout>28000</journal-buffer-timeout>

      <journal-max-io>4096</journal-max-io>


    <connectors>
        <!-- Connector used to be announced through cluster connections and notifications -->
        <connector name="artemis">tcp://10.168.100.42:61616</connector>
        <connector name="netty-live-connector">tcp://10.168.100.41:61616</connector>
    </connectors>



      <!-- how often we are looking for how many bytes are being used on the disk in ms -->
      <disk-scan-period>5000</disk-scan-period>

      <max-disk-usage>90</max-disk-usage>

      <!-- should the broker detect dead locks and other issues -->
      <critical-analyzer>true</critical-analyzer>

      <critical-analyzer-timeout>120000</critical-analyzer-timeout>

      <critical-analyzer-check-period>60000</critical-analyzer-check-period>

      <critical-analyzer-policy>HALT</critical-analyzer-policy>

      
      <page-sync-timeout>356000</page-sync-timeout>

      <acceptors>
         <acceptor name="artemis">tcp://10.168.100.42:61616?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;amqpMinLargeMessageSize=102400;protocols=CORE,AMQP,STOMP,HORNETQ,MQTT,OPENWIRE;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300;amqpDuplicateDetection=true</acceptor>

         <acceptor name="amqp">tcp://10.168.100.41:5672?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=AMQP;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300;amqpMinLargeMessageSize=102400;amqpDuplicateDetection=true</acceptor>

         <acceptor name="stomp">tcp://10.168.100.41:61613?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=STOMP;useEpoll=true</acceptor>

         <acceptor name="hornetq">tcp://10.168.100.41:5445?anycastPrefix=jms.queue.;multicastPrefix=jms.topic.;protocols=HORNETQ,STOMP;useEpoll=true</acceptor>

         <acceptor name="mqtt">tcp://10.168.100.41:1883?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=MQTT;useEpoll=true</acceptor>

      </acceptors>


      <cluster-user>username</cluster-user>

      <cluster-password>password</cluster-password>

      <broadcast-groups>
         <broadcast-group name="bg-group1">
            <group-address>231.7.7.7</group-address>
            <group-port>9876</group-port>
            <broadcast-period>5000</broadcast-period>
            <connector-ref>artemis</connector-ref>
         </broadcast-group>
      </broadcast-groups>

      <discovery-groups>
         <discovery-group name="dg-group1">
            <group-address>231.7.7.7</group-address>
            <group-port>9876</group-port>
            <refresh-timeout>10000</refresh-timeout>
         </discovery-group>
      </discovery-groups>

      <cluster-connections>
         <cluster-connection name="my-cluster">
            <connector-ref>artemis</connector-ref>
            <message-load-balancing>ON_DEMAND</message-load-balancing>
            <max-hops>0</max-hops>
            <discovery-group-ref discovery-group-name="dg-group1"/>
         </cluster-connection>
      </cluster-connections>


      <ha-policy>
         <replication>
            <slave/>
         </replication>
      </ha-policy>

      <security-settings>
         <security-setting match="#">
            <permission type="createNonDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="deleteNonDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="createDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="deleteDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="createAddress" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="deleteAddress" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="consume" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="browse" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="send" roles="amq"/>
            <!-- we need this otherwise ./artemis data imp wouldn't work -->
            <permission type="manage" roles="amq"/>
         </security-setting>
      </security-settings>

      <address-settings>
         <!-- if you define auto-create on certain queues, management has to be auto-create -->
         <address-setting match="activemq.management#">
            <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
            <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
            <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
            <!-- with -1 only the global-max-size is in use for limiting -->
            <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
            <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
            <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
            <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
            <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
            <auto-create-jms-queues>true</auto-create-jms-queues>
            <auto-create-jms-topics>true</auto-create-jms-topics>
         </address-setting>
         <!--default for catch all-->
         <address-setting match="#">
            <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
            <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
            <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
            <!-- with -1 only the global-max-size is in use for limiting -->
            <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
            <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
            <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
            <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
            <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
            <auto-create-jms-queues>true</auto-create-jms-queues>
            <auto-create-jms-topics>true</auto-create-jms-topics>
         </address-setting>
      </address-settings>

      <addresses>
         <address name="DLQ">
            <anycast>
               <queue name="DLQ" />
            </anycast>
         </address>
         <address name="ExpiryQueue">
            <anycast>
               <queue name="ExpiryQueue" />
            </anycast>
         </address>

      </addresses>
   </core>
</configuration>
```

When I start master and slave they are started without any issue, but master and slave are not in sync:
[image: Below is console screenshot from master]

master.log is

```
INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.integration.bootstrap] AMQ101000: Starting ActiveMQ Artemis Server
INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221000: live Message Broker is starting with configuration Broker Configuration (clustered=true,journalDirectory=data/journal,bindingsDirectory=data/bindings,largeMessagesDirectory=data/large-messages,pagingDirectory=data/paging)
INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221012: Using AIO Journal
INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221057: Global Max Size is being adjusted to 1/2 of the JVM max size (-Xmx). being defined as 1,073,741,824
INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-server]. Adding protocol support for: CORE
INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-amqp-protocol]. Adding protocol support for: AMQP
INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-hornetq-protocol]. Adding protocol support for: HORNETQ
INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-mqtt-protocol]. Adding protocol support for: MQTT
INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-openwire-protocol]. Adding protocol support for: OPENWIRE
INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-stomp-protocol]. Adding protocol support for: STOMP
INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221080: Deploying address DLQ supporting [ANYCAST]
INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221003: Deploying ANYCAST queue DLQ on address DLQ
INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221080: Deploying address ExpiryQueue supporting [ANYCAST]
INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221003: Deploying ANYCAST queue ExpiryQueue on address ExpiryQueue
INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221020: Started EPOLL Acceptor at 10.168.100.41:61616 for protocols [CORE,MQTT,AMQP,STOMP,HORNETQ,OPENWIRE]
INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221020: Started EPOLL Acceptor at 10.168.100.41:5445 for protocols [HORNETQ,STOMP]
INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221020: Started EPOLL Acceptor at 10.168.100.41:5672 for protocols [AMQP]
INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221020: Started EPOLL Acceptor at 10.168.100.41:1883 for protocols [MQTT]
INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221020: Started EPOLL Acceptor at 10.168.100.41:61613 for protocols [STOMP]
INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221007: Server is now live
INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221001: Apache ActiveMQ Artemis Message Broker version 2.16.0 [10.168.100.41, nodeID=05cefba8-38e1-11eb-9570-024236bc469a] 
INFO  [org.apache.activemq.hawtio.branding.PluginContextListener] Initialized activemq-branding plugin
INFO  [org.apache.activemq.hawtio.plugin.PluginContextListener] Initialized artemis-plugin plugin
INFO  [io.hawt.HawtioContextListener] Initialising hawtio services
INFO  [io.hawt.system.ConfigManager] Configuration will be discovered via system properties
INFO  [io.hawt.jmx.JmxTreeWatcher] Welcome to Hawtio 2.11.0
INFO  [io.hawt.web.auth.AuthenticationConfiguration] Starting hawtio authentication filter, JAAS realm: "activemq" authorized role(s): "amq" role principal classes: "org.apache.activemq.artemis.spi.core.security.jaas.RolePrincipal"
INFO  [io.hawt.web.proxy.ProxyServlet] Proxy servlet is disabled
INFO  [io.hawt.web.servlets.JolokiaConfiguredAgentServlet] Jolokia overridden property: [key=policyLocation, value=file:/gcdata/amq/data/etc/jolokia-access.xml]
INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis] AMQ241001: HTTP Server started at http://localhost:8161
INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis] AMQ241002: Artemis Jolokia REST API available at http://localhost:8161/console/jolokia
INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis] AMQ241004: Artemis Console available at http://localhost:8161/console
INFO  [io.hawt.web.auth.LoginServlet] Hawtio login is using 1800 sec. HttpSession timeout
INFO  [io.hawt.web.auth.LoginServlet] Logging in user: user
INFO  [io.hawt.web.auth.keycloak.KeycloakServlet] Keycloak integration is disabled
INFO  [io.hawt.web.auth.SessionExpiryFilter] Expiring session due to inactivity
```

slave log :

```
INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.integration.bootstrap] AMQ101000: Starting ActiveMQ Artemis Server
INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221000: backup Message Broker is starting with configuration Broker Configuration (clustered=true,journalDirectory=data/journal,bindingsDirectory=data/bindings,largeMessagesDirectory=data/large-messages,pagingDirectory=data/paging)
INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221055: There were too many old replicated folders upon startup, removing /gcdata/amq/data/data/journal/oldreplica.4
INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222162: Moving data directory /gcdata/amq/data/data/journal to /gcdata/amq/data/data/journal/oldreplica.6
INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221012: Using AIO Journal
INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221057: Global Max Size is being adjusted to 1/2 of the JVM max size (-Xmx). being defined as 1,073,741,824
INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-server]. Adding protocol support for: CORE
INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-amqp-protocol]. Adding protocol support for: AMQP
INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-hornetq-protocol]. Adding protocol support for: HORNETQ
INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-mqtt-protocol]. Adding protocol support for: MQTT
INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-openwire-protocol]. Adding protocol support for: OPENWIRE
INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-stomp-protocol]. Adding protocol support for: STOMP
INFO  [org.apache.activemq.hawtio.branding.PluginContextListener] Initialized activemq-branding plugin
INFO  [org.apache.activemq.hawtio.plugin.PluginContextListener] Initialized artemis-plugin plugin
INFO  [io.hawt.HawtioContextListener] Initialising hawtio services
INFO  [io.hawt.system.ConfigManager] Configuration will be discovered via system properties
INFO  [io.hawt.jmx.JmxTreeWatcher] Welcome to Hawtio 2.11.0
INFO  [io.hawt.web.auth.AuthenticationConfiguration] Starting hawtio authentication filter, JAAS realm: "activemq" authorized role(s): "amq" role principal classes: "org.apache.activemq.artemis.spi.core.security.jaas.RolePrincipal"
INFO  [io.hawt.web.proxy.ProxyServlet] Proxy servlet is disabled
INFO  [io.hawt.web.servlets.JolokiaConfiguredAgentServlet] Jolokia overridden property: [key=policyLocation, value=file:/gcdata/amq/data/etc/jolokia-access.xml]
INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis] AMQ241001: HTTP Server started at http://localhost:8161
INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis] AMQ241002: Artemis Jolokia REST API available at http://localhost:8161/console/jolokia
INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis] AMQ241004: Artemis Console available at http://localhost:8161/console
```

I used `iperf` to test connectivity and result is:

```
~$ iperf -s -u -B 10.168.100.41 -i 1 
------------------------------------------------------------ 
Server listening on UDP port 5001 
Binding to local address 10.168.100.41 
Receiving 1470 byte datagrams 
UDP buffer size: 208 KByte (default) 
------------------------------------------------------------ 
[ 3] local 10.168.100.41 port 5001 connected with 10.168.100.42 port 41425
[ ID] Interval Transfer Bandwidth Jitter Lost/Total Datagrams 
[ 3] 0.0- 1.0 sec 129 KBytes 1.06 Mbits/sec 0.024 ms 0/ 90 (0%) 
...
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: I am running brokers in VM environments and internally UDP multicast is open and available

Comment: Your slave `broker.xml` has acceptors binding to `10.168.100.41` which seems wrong since that's also where the master's `broker.xml` is binding. Also, the `<name>` of both brokers is `10.168.100.41` which seems wrong as well. Can you include the `artemis.log` from both the master and the slave which includes the start-up process?

Comment: I used iperf to test connectivity  and result is 

~$ iperf -s -u -B 10.168.100.41 -i 1
------------------------------------------------------------
Server listening on UDP port 5001
Binding to local address 10.168.100.41
Receiving 1470 byte datagrams
UDP buffer size:  208 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
[  3] local 10.168.100.41 port 5001 connected with 10.168.100.42 port 41425
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth        Jitter   Lost/Total Datagrams
[  3]  0.0- 1.0 sec   129 KBytes  1.06 Mbits/sec   0.024 ms    0/   90 (0%)
...

Comment: The configuration looks fine to me. This seems like something environmental. Does it work if you run both brokers on the same machine? You'll need to change the ports on the slave's acceptors to make this work, but it should be pretty straight-forward.

Comment: Thanks @JustinBertram ... I will try to run both brokers on same machine

Comment: same machine setup took 5-10 mins and it's up and running ... I don't what's wrong with networked stuff .. May be firewall (I check already and it works) Or something else .. I'll dig a bit more on network accessibility and will share if I find something

Comment: @JustinBertram I checked network and found no issue but still I couldn't setup master-slave on 2 different machines. Eventually I ended up pulling docker image from [link]https://hub.docker.com/r/vromero/activemq-artemis and deployed in docker stack which gives me almost similar solution ..

Comment: What exactly do you mean it "gives me almost similar solution"? Does that mean it works or it doesn't work?

Comment: I mean it it gives me seemless failover. ... Actually Docker stack has 3 nodes. if node where artemis is deployed, goes down, swarmpit deploys all images running on that node to other working nodes.

Comment: If you deploy ActiveMQ Artemis into any kind of environment which automatically manages broker deployment then there's no need to configure normal high-availability within the broker itself. You simple need to configure the broker to use a persistent store (e.g. via NFS, SAN, etc.). If the broker fails then the environment will automatically restart the broker and it will reconnect to the persistent store and clients can reconnect and carry on as normal just like they would if they failed over to a backup. This is one of the main benefits of cloud environments.

Comment: @RafaqatAli did you find any solution for this issue ? I'm having the same problem and cant find any solution

Comment: @LDropl Unfortunately, I couldn't find any solution for this. I created docker image of AMQ and deployed it in docker stack which somehow works for me at this stage

Answer (score 1):

Try to specify the `local-bind-address` parameter in broadcast and discovery groups. If this property is not specified when having multiple network interfaces, then the socket will be bound to the wildcard address, an IP address chosen by the kernel.

Master:

```xml
<name>10.168.100.41</name>

<connectors>
    <connector name="artemis">tcp://10.168.100.41:61616</connector>
</connectors>

<broadcast-groups>
    <broadcast-group name="bg-group1">
        <local-bind-address>10.168.100.41</local-bind-address>
        <group-address>231.7.7.7</group-address>
        <group-port>9876</group-port>
        <broadcast-period>5000</broadcast-period>
        <connector-ref>artemis</connector-ref>
    </broadcast-group>
</broadcast-groups>

<discovery-groups>
    <discovery-group name="dg-group1">
        <local-bind-address>10.168.100.41</local-bind-address>
        <group-address>231.7.7.7</group-address>
        <group-port>9876</group-port>
        <refresh-timeout>10000</refresh-timeout>
    </discovery-group>
</discovery-groups>
```

Slave:

```xml
<name>10.168.100.42</name>

<connectors>
    <connector name="artemis">tcp://10.168.100.42:61616</connector>
</connectors>

<broadcast-groups>
    <broadcast-group name="bg-group1">
        <local-bind-address>10.168.100.42</local-bind-address>
        <group-address>231.7.7.7</group-address>
        <group-port>9876</group-port>
        <broadcast-period>5000</broadcast-period>
        <connector-ref>artemis</connector-ref>
    </broadcast-group>
</broadcast-groups>

<discovery-groups>
    <discovery-group name="dg-group1">
        <local-bind-address>10.168.100.42</local-bind-address>
        <group-address>231.7.7.7</group-address>
        <group-port>9876</group-port>
        <refresh-timeout>10000</refresh-timeout>
    </discovery-group>
</discovery-groups>
```

Given that replication is a shared-nothing architecture, having 3 master-slave nodes (6 brokers in total) will mitigate against the risk of split-brain thanks to the quorum voting mechanism. To enable this, you should have an odd number of live nodes greater than one (i.e. 3, 5, 7 and so on).

Comment: How does slave node know what is master node address? Where do we establish link between master and slave?

Comment: In this case, the cluster topology is sent around over cluster connections (dynamic discovert mechanism). You may also want to take a look at the static configuration where you provide the list of initial connectors.